# Downgrade mysql 8.0.27 to 8.0.26 ubuntu 20.04

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, percona

I set up a new AWS EC2 instance with Ubuntu 20.04, php, Apache, and mySQL.  I also installed N-Able (Solarwinds) server backup.

I am able to do system and file backups but the mySQL backup fails. N-Able uses Percona XtraBackup for this function.  N-Able support was able to narrow this down to the version check.  Percona claims support mySQL 8.0, but their version check code fails current mySQL (8.0.27). Percona release notes only references 8.0.26.

When I do "sudo apt install mysql-server" I get 8.0.27.  How can I downgrade that to 8.0.26?

Comment: Here is that file. Its hard to find after Ubuntu updates the packages on their servers https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mysql-8.0/8.0.26-0ubuntu0.20.04.2

Comment: Database admin related questions should be asked on the dedicated DBA sister site of SO, not on the programming focused SO.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, in-place downgrades with MySQL 8.0 is not supported:

> "Downgrade from MySQL 8.0 to MySQL 5.7, or from a MySQL 8.0 release to
> a previous MySQL 8.0 release, is not supported. The only supported
> alternative is to restore a backup taken before upgrading. It is
> therefore imperative that you back up your data before starting the
> upgrade process."

Source: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/downgrading.html

However, there is still a way to downgrade: You can use `mysqldump` to make a full logical backup of your databases, then uninstall the MySQL 8.0.27 packages, remove your datadir (defaults to `/var/lib/mysql/` ), install the mysql 8.0.26 packages and then restore your databases from the logical backup.

Something like this (skipping params for credential for `mysqldump` and `mysql`):

```
mysqldump -uroot -p --all-databases > /tmp/all-databases.sql
sudo apt-get uninstall mysql-server
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql
sudo apt-get install mysql-server=8.0.26
# make sure the mysql server is started, then:
mysql < /tmp/all-databases.sql
```

Disclaimer: I've typed this from memory while on a mobile phone, so can't guarantee the accuracy and safety of the above commands.

Answer (score 1):

uninstall mysql

command

```
dpkg --list|grep mysql
sudo apt-get remove mysql-common
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge mysql-server-"version"
dpkg -l|grep ^rc|awk '{print$2}'|sudo xargs dpkg -P
dpkg --list|grep mysql
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge mysql-apt-config
```

end reboot

install mysql
Go to the official download

Answer (score 0):

setup 1 download 8.0.26
address:https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/community/

Product Version:8.0.26
Operating System:Ubuntu Linux
OS Version:Ubuntu Linux 20.04 (x86, 64-bit)

chose DEB Bundle